# Retrieving Gene Ontology Hierarchy Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, bioinformatics, ontology-mapping

I'm trying parsing and hierarchical display of Gene Ontology (GO) terms from an OBO file using Python. While I have made progress, I'm encountering an issue with properly handling multiple is_a relationships within the same term. My goal is to achieve a hierarchical structure that considers all is_a relationships.

I'm working with a subset of the Gene Ontology data from the go-basic.obo file. Here's an example of the data format:

```
    format-version: 1.2
data-version: releases/2023-06-11
subsetdef: chebi_ph7_3 "Rhea list of ChEBI terms representing the major species at pH 7.3."
subsetdef: gocheck_do_not_annotate "Term not to be used for direct annotation"
subsetdef: gocheck_do_not_manually_annotate "Term not to be used for direct manual annotation"
subsetdef: goslim_agr "AGR slim"
subsetdef: goslim_aspergillus "Aspergillus GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_candida "Candida GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_chembl "ChEMBL protein targets summary"
subsetdef: goslim_drosophila "Drosophila GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_flybase_ribbon "FlyBase Drosophila GO ribbon slim"
subsetdef: goslim_generic "Generic GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_metagenomics "Metagenomics GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_mouse "Mouse GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_pir "PIR GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_plant "Plant GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_pombe "Fission yeast GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_synapse "synapse GO slim"
subsetdef: goslim_yeast "Yeast GO slim"
subsetdef: prokaryote_subset "GO subset for prokaryotes"
synonymtypedef: syngo_official_label "label approved by the SynGO project"
synonymtypedef: systematic_synonym "Systematic synonym" EXACT
default-namespace: gene_ontology
ontology: go

[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

[Term]
id: GO:0048308
name: organelle inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The partitioning of organelles between daughter cells at cell division." [GOC:jid]
subset: goslim_pir
subset: goslim_yeast
is_a: GO:0006996 ! organelle organization

[Term]
id: GO:0007029
name: endoplasmic reticulum organization
namespace: biological_process
def: "A process that is carried out at the cellular level which results in the assembly, arrangement of constituent parts, or disassembly of the endoplasmic reticulum." [GOC:dph, GOC:jl, GOC:mah]
subset: goslim_pir
synonym: "endoplasmic reticulum morphology" RELATED []
synonym: "endoplasmic reticulum organisation" EXACT []
synonym: "endoplasmic reticulum organization and biogenesis" RELATED [GOC:mah]
synonym: "ER organisation" EXACT []
synonym: "ER organization and biogenesis" RELATED [GOC:mah]
is_a: GO:0006996 ! organelle organization
relationship: part_of GO:0010256 ! endomembrane system organization

[Term]
id: GO:0048309
name: endoplasmic reticulum inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The partitioning of endoplasmic reticulum between daughter cells at cell division." [GOC:jid]
synonym: "ER inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0007029 ! endoplasmic reticulum organization
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

[Term]
id: GO:0048313
name: Golgi inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The partitioning of Golgi apparatus between daughter cells at cell division." [GOC:jid, PMID:12851069]
synonym: "Golgi apparatus inheritance" EXACT []
synonym: "Golgi division" EXACT [GOC:ascb_2009, GOC:dph, GOC:tb]
synonym: "Golgi partitioning" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0007030 ! Golgi organization
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

[Term]
id: GO:0007030
name: Golgi organization
namespace: biological_process
def: "A process that is carried out at the cellular level which results in the assembly, arrangement of constituent parts, or disassembly of the Golgi apparatus." [GOC:dph, GOC:jl, GOC:mah]
subset: goslim_pir
synonym: "Golgi apparatus organization" EXACT []
synonym: "Golgi organisation" EXACT []
synonym: "Golgi organization and biogenesis" RELATED [GOC:mah]
is_a: GO:0006996 ! organelle organization
relationship: part_of GO:0010256 ! endomembrane system organization

[Term]
id: GO:0090166
name: Golgi disassembly
namespace: biological_process
def: "A cellular process that results in the breakdown of a Golgi apparatus that contributes to Golgi inheritance." [GOC:ascb_2009, GOC:dph, GOC:tb]
synonym: "Golgi apparatus disassembly" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0007030 ! Golgi organization
is_a: GO:1903008 ! organelle disassembly
relationship: part_of GO:0048313 ! Golgi inheritance

[Term]
id: GO:1903008
name: organelle disassembly
namespace: biological_process
def: "The disaggregation of an organelle into its constituent components." [GO_REF:0000079, GOC:TermGenie]
synonym: "organelle degradation" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0006996 ! organelle organization
is_a: GO:0022411 ! cellular component disassembly


[Term]
id: GO:0006996
name: organelle organization
namespace: biological_process
alt_id: GO:1902589
def: "A process that is carried out at the cellular level which results in the assembly, arrangement of constituent parts, or disassembly of an organelle within a cell. An organelle is an organized structure of distinctive morphology and function. Includes the nucleus, mitochondria, plastids, vacuoles, vesicles, ribosomes and the cytoskeleton. Excludes the plasma membrane." [GOC:mah]
subset: goslim_candida
subset: goslim_pir
synonym: "organelle organisation" EXACT []
synonym: "organelle organization and biogenesis" RELATED [GOC:dph, GOC:jl, GOC:mah]
synonym: "single organism organelle organization" EXACT [GOC:TermGenie]
synonym: "single-organism organelle organization" RELATED []
is_a: GO:0016043 ! cellular component organization
```

I used this code

```
def parse_obo(file_path):
    terms = {}
    current_term = None
    
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                if current_term:
                    terms[current_term['id']] = current_term
                    current_term = None
            elif line.startswith('[Term]'):
                if current_term:
                    terms[current_term['id']] = current_term
                current_term = {'id': ''}
            elif current_term:
                parts = line.split(': ', 1)
                if len(parts) == 2:
                    current_term[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    
    return terms

def display_hierarchy(terms, term_id, indent=0):
    if term_id in terms:
        term = terms[term_id]
        print(' ' * indent + term_id)
        
        if 'is_a' in term:
            parent_ids = [parent.split()[1] for parent in term['is_a'] if len(parent.split()) > 1]
            for parent_id in parent_ids:
                display_hierarchy(terms, parent_id, indent + 4)

        if 'id' in term:
            child_ids = [child_id for child_id in terms if term_id in terms[child_id].get('is_a', [])]
            for child_id in child_ids:
                display_hierarchy(terms, child_id, indent + 4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = 'go-basic_1.obo'
    terms = parse_obo(file_path)
    
    for term_id in terms:
        display_hierarchy(terms, term_id, indent=0)
```

I got like this

```
GO:0000001
GO:0048308
    GO:0048309
    GO:0048313
GO:0007029
GO:0048309
GO:0048313
GO:0007030
GO:0090166
GO:1903008
    GO:0090166
GO:0006996
    GO:0048308
        GO:0048309
        GO:0048313
    GO:0007029
    GO:0007030
```

but I want result like this

```
GO:0016043
    GO:0006996
        GO:1903008
            GO:0090166
        GO:0048308
            GO:0000001
            GO:0048309
            GO:0048313
        GO:0007029
            GO:0048309
        GO:0007030
            GO:0048313
            GO:0090166
GO:0048311
    GO:0000001
GO:0022411
    GO:1903008
    GO:0090166
```

I want to plot result from my genomic data for gene ontology, so I started from here , kindly help

Comment: Why in the desired output is GO:0048311 included, but GO:0022411 and  GO:0016043 are not?

Comment: That should also come, in hirerchy, kindly help

Comment: Could you then update the question, so it is included in the expected output?

Comment: I am sorry, I hope my exact hirerchy may look like in my updated code

Comment: Shouldn't GO:1903008 look the same in both its occurrences? In one case it has a child and in another it doesn't.

Comment: so, it may be proper whith original file right

Comment: I don't understand your comment. GO:0090166 is child of GO:1903008. Why this is not reflected in the last line of your desired output, but it still appears like that on the 4th line of your desired output? Should this not be the same on both places?

Comment: Any clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to take care of these points:

- As `is_a` may occur multiple times per item, you would need to collect them in a collection, as otherwise you will overwrite a previous value and only retain the last value encountered per term. I would generalise this, and make all items in a term to have list values, except maybe for `id`, which should occur only once per term
- To display the hierarchy you would benefit from having the relation from parent to children, instead of child to parents. So I would suggest including a separate function to add this inversed relationship to the terms.

Here is how that would look:

```
def parse_obo(file_path):
    terms = {}
    current_term = {}
    isterm = False
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            isterm = isterm or line.startswith('id:')
            if isterm and ": " in line:
                key, value = line.split(': ', 1)
                if key == "id":
                    current_term = terms.setdefault(value, {})
                    current_term["id"] = value
                else:
                    current_term.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
    return terms

def make_hierarchy(terms):
    for term in list(terms.values()):
        term.setdefault("children", [])
        if "is_a" in term:
            for is_a in term["is_a"]:
                parent = is_a.split()[0]
                terms.setdefault(parent, { 'id': parent }).setdefault("children", []).append(term)
    return [term for term in terms.values() if "is_a" not in term]
    
def display_hierarchy(terms, indent=""):
    for term in terms:
        print(f"{indent}{term['id']}")
        display_hierarchy(term['children'], indent + "  ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = 'go-basic_1.obo'
    terms = parse_obo(file_path)
    roots = make_hierarchy(terms)
    display_hierarchy(roots)
```

Comment: thank you, this gave 
GO:0006996
  GO:0048308
    GO:0000001
    GO:0048309
    GO:0048313
  GO:0007029
    GO:0048309
  GO:0007030
    GO:0048313
    GO:0090166
  GO:1903008
    GO:0090166
still last line didnt come

Comment: Updated to also include nodes in the output that are not listed in `id: ` entries, but only in `is_a: ` entries. In this output, both occurrences of GO:1903008 have the same child.